# Getting avatar URLs for other users.

Tags: box-api

When retrieving comments made on a Box file, the comments may have been made by a user other than the current user.

The comment object contains the user name and id, but not the avatarUrl.

Making a call to users/me works for the current user. 
I tried users/userId for another user (the one who made the comment), and it does not seem to work.

Is there another entry point to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope - you can only access the authenticated user's information.

If they opened the API call to any user, then a malicious attacker could download all of box's user information. I realize this is not your intent - this is just Box trying to protect itself.